# raspberrypi linux compiling on YOSEMITE got error

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

When i compile the official linux kernel on my macbook follow this http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/configuring.md tutorial i got an error about Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.
Have someone done this successfully?
I think it should be some thing about -lstdc++.
Please help me.

Comment: are you compiling the kernel for x86_64 architeture for raspberrypi ?

Comment: The tutorial is for compiling the kernel on the Pi. If you wan't to compile on another machine then you will need to look into cross compilation which is not a trivial task.

Comment: sorry my bad i am compiling with this CROSS-COMPILING tutorial http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md and get error when make.

Comment: Tutorial recommend Ubuntu to compile linux,their tools https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools seems like not work on mac os :(